# Como ordeno alfabeticamente un arreglo string en java

Tags: java, array

Tengo un problema al ordenar mi arreglo string nombres, intente usar el Arrays.sort(); pero no funciono aqui mi codigo.

```
package mainclass;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Personas {
   public static Scanner leer=new Scanner(System.in);
   public static String nombre[]=new String[5];
   public static int edad[]=new int[5];
   public static double altura[]=new double[5]; 
   public static int peso[]=new int[5];
   public static String sexo[]=new String[5];
   public static int Contador;
   public static String ComparaNom;

   public static void registrar(){

       if(Contador<5)
       {
       System.out.println("Nombre: ");
       nombre[Contador]=leer.next();
       System.out.println("Edad: ");
       edad[Contador]=leer.nextInt();
       System.out.println("Altura: ");
       altura[Contador]=leer.nextDouble();
       Contador++;

       }

       else
       {
           System.out.println("No hay mas espacio...");
       }
   }
   public static void borrar(){
       System.out.println("Borrar: "); ComparaNom=leer.next();
       for(int i=0;i<Contador;i++){
           if(ComparaNom.equals(nombre[i])){
               for(int z=i;z<Contador;z++){
                   nombre[z]=nombre[z+1];
                   edad[z]=edad[z+1];
                   altura[z]=altura[z+1];
               }
           }
       }Contador--;
   }
   public static void modificar(){
       System.out.println("Modificar: "); ComparaNom=leer.next();
       for(int i=0; i<Contador;i++){
           if(ComparaNom.equals(nombre[i])){
               System.out.println("Nombre: ");
               nombre[i]=leer.next();
               System.out.println("Edad: ");
               edad[i]=leer.nextInt();
               System.out.println("Altura: ");
               altura[i]=leer.nextDouble();
           }
       }
   }
   public static void busqueda(){
       System.out.println("Buscar: "); ComparaNom=leer.next();
       for(int i=0;i<Contador;i++){
           if(nombre[i].equals(ComparaNom)){
               System.out.println("Nombre: "+nombre[i]);
               System.out.println("Edad: "+edad[i]);
               System.out.println("Altura: "+altura[i]);
           }
       }
   }
   public static void general(){

       for(int i=0;i<Contador;i++){
           System.out.println("");
           System.out.println("Nombre: "+nombre[i]);
           System.out.println("Edad: "+edad[i]);
           System.out.println("Altura: "+altura[i]);
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: Lo que necesitas es ordenar alfabéticamente tu array public static String nombre[]=new String[5]; ? Podías agregar lo que has intentado? En tu código no se ve ninguna referencia a Arrays.sort()

Comment: Se lo quite porque no realizaba nada, si lo que quiero es ordenar alfabeticamente mi String nombre[] y habia utlizado Arrays.sort(nombre); pero me da un error.

Comment: Arrays.sort() utiliza el metodo compareTo para el caso de Strings eso corresponde a orden lexicográfico, por lo que debería funcionar (Ejemplo: https://ideone.com/kHOQ5b). Podrías colocar lo que intentaste y el error que obtuviste?

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at java.util.ComparableTimSort.countRunAndMakeAscending(ComparableTimSort.java:321)
 at java.util.ComparableTimSort.sort(ComparableTimSort.java:188)
 at java.util.Arrays.sort(Arrays.java:1246)
 at mainclass.Personas.general(Personas.java:81)
 at mainclass.MainClass.main(MainClass.java:38)
C:\Users\Pedro\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.2\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 47 seconds)

Comment: Revisa si tienes uno o más elementos nulos en tu array 'nombre'

Comment: El problema son los nulos? porque tengo que ordenarlos conforme el numero de clientes dados de alta, si solo tengo 3 clientes, tengo que ordenar los 3.

Comment: Si, en ese caso si tu cantidad de clientes es variable y no puedes determinarlo desde el momento de la inicialización del array 'persona' puedes utilizar una Lista. La inicializas vacía y le vas agregando los clientes. Luego para ordenarla: List<String> nombres =Arrays.asList("Juan", "Pedro", "Antonio");
   Collections.sort(nombres);

Comment: Entonces seria List<String> nombres=Arrays.alList(nombre);?

Comment: Si hicieras eso estarías primero construyendo el array 'nombre' para luego crear una lista a partir de él, lo cual no tiene sentido porque justamente no sabes cuantos elementos vas a tener y por eso no es conveniente utilizar un array. A su vez sería poco óptimo ya que inicializarías dos estructuras cuando vas a utilizar solo una. Lo que quise decir es inicializar una lista, instanciada como ArrayList: List<String> nombres = new ArrayList(); y luego ir agregándole elementos mediante .add(): 
   nombres.add(leer.next());

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La razón por la que estás teniendo estos problemas es que el método `nextInt();`, el método `nextDouble();`, están dejando “residuos” en el buffer. Concretamente el salto de línea *‘\n’* ya que no forma parte del número y en la siguiente introducción de datos, antes de introducirlos, detecta que hay datos en el buffer y los coge. 
Estoy seguro que habrás observado que en algunas sentencias no introduces datos y, que automáticamente salta a la siguiente instrucción. Razón de lo comentado anteriormente. Por eso mismo, la sentencia `Arrays.sort(nombre);` te devuelve un fallo basado en que no todas las variables estén correctamente inicializadas.

Para solucionar esto, antes de la sentencia que salta automáticamente sin meter datos, debes limpiar el buffer, introduciendo previamente a dónde “salta” la sentencia `leer.nextLine();`

[Leer más](https://blogdelingeniero1.wordpress.com/2014/06/08/limpiar-el-buffer-de-entrada-en-java/)